# Email Frequency does not update on Preferences page

Tags: bug

Changing e-mail preferences from **daily** to **every 3 hours** on *Edit Profile & Settings* -> *Preferences* page, and then clicking **Save email settings** button, the message **"you will now receive unread inbox messages via email every 3 hours"** pops up.

When refreshing Preferences page, the selection is set to daily again. This might be a temporary or visual bug. Did my preferences change?